# Plugging a value to a released image?

Tags: c++, opencv

I saw in code using openCV the following:

```
        cvReleaseImage(&img);
        img= 0;
```

Why and how do they put 0 in the image after they released it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Some people believe that zeroing a pointer after deletion, will help them catch bugs.

The OpenCV authors evidently thought so, hence, `cvReleaseImage` does that.

And then the author of the code you’ve shown also believed that, and probably was not aware that `cvReleaseImage` already does that zeroing.

So, the extra zeroing is 100% redundant, just unnecessary code.

The zeroing done by `cvReleaseImage` is believed by some to help with catching bugs, while others believe the opposite, that it instead mainly hides bugs.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

It is not the image itself, it is a pointer to the image that they set to 0 (NULL) after the image has been released.

Answer (score 0):

It ensures that the image pointer will not point to something else. Later, you also can check whether the pointer is point to NULL (which is 0).

Hope it helps.